# SyntaxError: Unexpected token at acorn.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I tried to create login form with `express.js` and jade template then I found an error like these:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (16:50)
    at Parser.pp.raise (C:\project\restaurant\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:943:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\project\restaurant\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1503:8)
    at Parser.pp.expect (C:\project\restaurant\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:1497:26)
    at Parser.pp.parseParenExpression (C:\project\restaurant\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:342:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (C:\project\restaurant\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:399:16)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (C:\project\restaurant\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:297:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (C:\project\restaurant\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:216:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (C:\project\restaurant\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:197:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (C:\project\restaurant\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:151:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (C:\project\restaurant\node_modules\acorn\dist\acorn.js:133:19)
```

This is my code for `layout.jade`:

```
doctype html

html

        head
                title #{Project Restaurant Finder} 
                link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
        body
                block content   
        Footer
                p contact : aliwumpa@gmail.com or 081222843778
```

This is my code for `index.jade`:

```
extends layout

block content

h1 = login form

    form(name ="login restaurant finder",method ="post")
        div.input
            span.label Login as Guest
            input(type="text", name="username")
        div.actions
            input(type="submit", value="ok")
```

Comment: I don't know if this is what's causing the error, but this part `title #{Project Restaurant Finder}` definitely needs fixing: Either change to `title Project Restaurant Finder` or to `title #{variable_name}`, where `variable_name` is the variable that you pass to the template to give it a title.

Answer (score 1):

Answer courtesy of [gandreadis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6171547/gandreadis) in the comments:

this part title `#{Project Restaurant Finder}` definitely needs fixing: Either change to title Project Restaurant Finder or to title `#{variable_name}`, where `variable_name` is the variable that you pass to the template to give it a title.